# Do you need to return money collected through a GoFundMe if the money isn't used for the intended project?

Tags: united-states, fraud, finance

Do you need to return money collected through a GoFundMe if the money isn't used for the intended project? Let's say you start a GoFundMe to make a game, you spend 50% of the money to make a game, but then the project is shelved indefinitely, because you have a burn out, can you keep the money until you feel like working again on the project or do you have to return it? I am wondering if there are edge cases and I am wondering how much can you get away with in similar situations.

Comment: I believe you will find the answer if you read the Go Fund Me terms and conditions that you agreed to when you started your campaign.